# Remove duplicate entries from nested dictionary, if two values are the same, in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.5

Consider this dictionary format.

```
{1:{'name':'chrome', 'author':'google', 'url':'http://www.google.com/' },
 2:{'name':'firefox','author':'mozilla','url':'http://www.mozilla.com/'}}
```

I want to remove all items which have the same name and author.

I can easily remove duplicate entries based on keys by putting all keys in a set, and maybe expand this to work on a specific value, but this seems like a costly operation which iterates over a dictionary multiple times. I wouldn't know how to do this with two values in an efficient way. It's a dictionary with thousands of items.

Comment: How do you get this data? You could build it using a dictionary mapping (name, author) pairs to the URL in the first place, then therfe would be no need to do this at all.

Comment: May be just change a structure of the dict and set the name and the author are the key of dict ?

Comment: I didn't specifically mention it, but I also want to count the removed items for internal reference, by doing `len(dict)` before and after. And changing the structure makes no difference, because I remove duplicate keys too. I've simplified the dictionary in the example a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through the dictionary, keeping track of encountered `(name, author)` tuples as you go and remove those that you have already encountered:

```
def remove_duplicates(d):
    encountered_entries = set()
    for key, entry in d.items():
        if (entry['name'], entry['author']) in encountered_entries:
            del d[key]
        else:
            encountered_entries.add((entry['name'], entry['author']))
```

Comment: It is not allowed to change a dict while iterating over `d.keys()` -- this gives undefined results.

Comment: @Sven: Iterating over `d.keys()` and changing the dict is ok in Python 2.5 (which this question is about). `d.keys()` returns a list of the keys in the dict, and this list isn't affected by subsequent modification of the dict. Modifying the dict while iterating over the dict itself, or over `d.iterkeys()`, `d.itervalues()` or `d.iteritems()` isn't ok, however.

Comment: @Pär: You are right :)  I always use `iterkeys()` to avoid the intermediate list.

Comment: You could change the loop to `for key, entry in d.items():` to save one line :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if this works...

```
from itertools import groupby

def entry_key(entry):
    key, value = entry
    return (value['name'], value['author'])

def nub(d):
    items = d.items()
    items.sort(key=entry_key)
    grouped = groupby(items, entry_key)
    return dict([grouper.next() for (key, grouper) in grouped])
```

Comment: I tried this, but Python 2.5 doesn't have `next()`. Maybe I should've put this in the text, instead of just a tag.

Comment: Oh, ok. Just use .next() then.

Comment: Thanks, it works. However I have profiled it and the other answer is about twice as fast.